# Mail.app has no entry for from: gmail-account

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

I'm using OSX10.11.4. I've got several mail accounts and use mail.app to receive and send mails. One of these accounts is a gmail Account. I'm able to receive all mails with mail.app but I can't send a mail from my gmail Account.

With all other accounts it's possible to receive and send, gmail is the only one where I'm only able to receive but not to send mails. If I want to send a mail the gmail account is not listed at the *from* dropdown-field.

I used default settings to set up the account at mail.app and does not change something.

Hope someone has an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by creating an app password for my gmail account and used it. After this I had to *restart* Mail.app and now it's possible to choose gmail-Account at from-list.

Answer (score 0):

You could just go into Mail/Preferences/Outgoing Mail settings and verify the SMTP settings. 
Gmail uses smtp.gmail.com on port 465